# Checking state after promise in initial function promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have this function:

```
  startGame = () => {
    this.buildDeck()
    .then(this.shuffleDeck)
    .then(this.dealToPlayer)
    .then(setTimeout(this.dealToPlayer, 2000))
    .then(setTimeout(this.dealToDealer, 4000))
  }
```

I am trying to test it by doing:

```
  it('expects playersHand to have 2 cards once game started', () => {
    wrapper.instance().startGame();
    expect(wrapper.state('playersHand').length).toEqual(2);
  });
```

however, it is saying received 0 because I believe it is not waiting for the promise to fully execute. how can I wait for the promise to finish before I then run the test?

I have tried `.update()` but that doesn't really do anything

Comment: I don't think this solves your problem, but ```.then(setTimeout(this.dealToPlayer, 2000))``` does not do what you may think it does. It should be ```.then(() => setTimeout(this.dealToPlayer, 2000))```

Comment: @Carcigenicate how so? `wrapper.instance().startGame().then(() => etc`?

Comment: @StefanOctavian but it works? and isn't that the shorthand of then...

Comment: @The walrus, if you write it like that, you won't set the timeout when the promise reaches ```then```, but the moment you set ```then```. You need to put it inside a function so that you can pass that function reference to ```then```, else you are passing a number which represents an id of the timeout (used to clear it if necessary)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm confused as to how to fix the problem :/

Comment: @Carcigenicate cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your startGame function to return the promise. Also fix the setTimeout issue others have mentioned. It should look like this

```
  startGame = () => {
    return this.buildDeck()
      .then(this.shuffleDeck)
      .then(this.dealToPlayer)
      .then(() => setTimeout(this.dealToPlayer, 2000))
      .then(() => setTimeout(this.dealToDealer, 4000))
  }
```

You have two different types of async going on here; promises and timers. You need to ensure both the promise has resolved and the timers have run before you can make your assertion. You can do that with a test like this (assuming you are using Jest):

```
it('expects playersHand to have 2 cards once game started', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  await wrapper.instance().startGame();
  jest.runAllTimers();
  expect(wrapper.state('playersHand').length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: wow, this is amazing. I'm gonna read the docs but can you quickly explain what the jest methods do?

Comment: The useFakeTimers function mocks timer methods (in this case setTimeout). You basically just need to call it at the beginning of tests where you intend to mock setTimeout, setInterval etc. After they are mocked, you can call runAllTimers anywhere in your tests to programmatically execute the timers. Docs are good (https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html).